# use deployJava.js to call java methods in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html, applet

I want to call java methods in javascript and  Andrew Thompson suggested to use the deployJava.js library for this. I followed these instructions:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html

Here is explained how to use the java class in javascript, but I would like to call the java methods from within the javascript. (This is because I want to import a .owl file in java en export the information in json-format to my code written in javascript.)
Does anybody know how to do this with the deployJava library?

This is my code to import the java file:

```
<noscript>A browser with JavaScript enabled is required for this page to operate properly.</noscript>
    <h1>Sending Messages to Other Applets</h1>
    <script>
        function sendMsgToIncrementCounter() {
        receiver.incrementCounter();
    }
</script>

<p>Sender Applet</p>
<script>
    var attributes = { id:'sender', code:'Sender.class', width:300, height:50} ;
    var parameters = {} ;
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6');
</script>
<br/>
<br/>
<p>Receiver Applet</p>
<script>
    var attributes = { id:'receiver', code:'../Receiver.class', width:300, height:50} ;
    var parameters = {} ;
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6');
</script>
```

and this is are the sender and receiver java files:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Receiver extends JApplet {
    private int ctr = 0;
    private JLabel  ctrLbl = null;

    public void init() {
        //Execute a job on the event-dispatching thread; creating this applet's GUI.
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {             
                    ctrLbl = new JLabel("");
                    add(ctrLbl);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Could not create applet's GUI");
        }
    }

    public void incrementCounter() {
        ctr++;
        String text = " Current Value Of Counter: " + (new Integer(ctr)).toString();
        ctrLbl.setText(text);
    }
}

import javax.swing.*;
```

import java.awt.event.*;
import netscape.javascript.*;

public class Sender extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

```
public void init() {
    //Execute a job on the event-dispatching thread; creating this applet's GUI.
    try {
        final ActionListener al = this;
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JButton btn = new JButton("Click To Increment Counter");
                add(btn);
                btn.addActionListener(al);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("createGUI didn't complete successfully");
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
        JSObject window = JSObject.getWindow(this);
        window.eval("sendMsgToIncrementCounter()");
    } catch (JSException jse) {
        jse.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

I just copy-paste this from the example given on this site:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/iac.html
This example works perfect in my browser, so the way it is done is correct, but I suspect that I don't import the javafiles correct, since this are the errors from je java-console:

```
load: class Sender.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Sender.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Applet2ClassLoader.java:195)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:249)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:179)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:690)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Plugin2Manager.java:3045)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1497)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Sender.class
```

Comment: As an aside.  Is this a server/client as suggested by the class names?  If so, look into the [3 methods in `AppletContext` that have 'stream' in the name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/AppletContext.html#setStream%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream%29).  They allow applets in the same JRE to communicate directly with each other.

Comment: Also, if you have discovered the answer, please enter it as an 'Answer' & accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the directory of the .class files given in the attributes. Here is the correct code:

```
<p>Sender Applet</p>
<script>
    var attributes = { id:'sender', code:'sesame/Sender.class', archive:'sesame/applet_SenderReceiver.jar', width:300, height:50} ;
    var parameters = {} ;
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6');
</script>
<br/>
<br/>
<p>Receiver Applet</p>
<script>
    var attributes = { id:'receiver', code:'sesame/Receiver.class', archive:'sesame/applet_SenderReceiver.jar', width:300, height:50} ;
    var parameters = {} ;
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining your original method, with the new JS snippet, and part of the accepted answer on your last question (tweaked), gives..

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
// dangerous to have a 0x0 applet!  Some security plug-ins regard it 
// as suspicious & automatically remove the element.  Better to set it
// not visible using styles
var attributes = {
    codebase:'../sesame',
    code:'applet_test',
    width:10, 
    height:10
};
var parameters = {fontSize:16} ;
var version = '1.6' ;
deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);

function test() {
    var app = document.applet_test;
    alert("Screen Dimension\r\n  width:" + app.getScreenWidth()
        + " height:" + app.getScreenHeight());
}
</script>
<body>

<FORM>
<INPUT 
    type="button" 
    value="call JAVA"
    onClick = "test()">
</FORM>

<script>
deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But I just wrote that up off the top of my head.  Don't trust me, trust a [validation service](http://validator.w3.org/). ;)

Comment: I think that the problem with this is that there isn't a connection between de test-procedure (it gets the object applet_test) and the applet deployed at the bottom: deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version); I updated my information in the question.

Comment: I have got it working now, like I thought it was a problem with the directory of the files themselves. I changed added the solution to my answer, thank you for all the help

Answer (score 1):

I would advise setting up a simple webservice that your javascript code can use. It doesn't need to be very involved, personally I'd use a simple REST layout with JAX-RS ([jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) is really nice to work with), especially if you want something simple with JSON support built-in (with the right plugin).

Trying to actually communicate with the applet on the page *might* be possible, but very browser dependent  and IMHO not worth the hassle. If you're working on the web, might as well use a web service.